# Graphics2D, как передавать например из массива объектов прорисовку каждого объекта на экран рисования?

Tags: java, графика

Как рисовать разобрался, а как передавать например из массива объектов прорисовку каждого объекта на экран рисования? Результат есть, а понимания как передается нет.

Код выдернутый из разных мест примера, который мне до сих пор непонятен:

```
private BufferedImage image;
private Graphics2D g;

image = new BufferedImage(WIDTH, HEIGHT, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
g = (Graphics2D) image.getGraphics();

Graphics g2 = this.getGraphics();
g2.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);
g2.dispose();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private BufferedImage image; // картинка
private Graphics2D g; //объект графики

image = new BufferedImage(WIDTH, HEIGHT, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB); //Создаем картинку шириной, высотой, и типом ARGB
g = (Graphics2D) image.getGraphics(); // получаем объект 2D графики

Graphics g2 = this.getGraphics(); // получаем объект графики
g2.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null); // рисуем на картинке
g2.dispose(); //освобождаем ресурсы
```

Comment: Может быть, рисуем картинку?